# pandas outliers with and without calculations

Tags: pandas, average, median, outliers

I'm contemplating making decisions on outliers on a dataset with over 300 features. I'd like to analyse the frame without removing the data hastingly. I have a frame:

```
 |    |   A |   B |    C |   D |   E |
 |---:|----:|----:|-----:|----:|----:|
 |  0 | 100 |  99 | 1000 | 300 | 250 |
 |  1 | 665 |   6 |    9 |   1 |   9 |
 |  2 |   7 | 665 |    4 |   9 |   1 |
 |  3 |   1 |   3 |    4 |   3 |   6 |
 |  4 |   1 |   9 |    1 | 665 |   5 |
 |  5 |   3 |   4 |    6 |   1 |   9 |
 |  6 |   5 |   9 |    1 |   3 |   2 |
 |  7 |   1 | 665 |    3 |   2 |   3 |
 |  8 |   2 | 665 |    9 |   1 |   0 |
 |  9 |   5 |   0 |    7 |   6 |   5 |
 | 10 |   0 |   3 |    3 |   7 |   3 |
 | 11 |   6 |   3 |    0 |   3 |   6 |
 | 12 |   6 |   6 |    5 |   1 |   5 |
```

I have coded some introspection to be saved in another frame called _outliers:

```
Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
IQR = (Q3 - Q1)
min_ = (Q1 - (1.5 * IQR))
max_ = (Q3 + (1.5 * IQR))
# Counts outliers in columns
_outliers = ((df.le (min_)) | (df.ge (max_))).sum().to_frame(name="outliers")
# Gives percentage of data that outliers represent in the column
_outliers["percent"] = (_outliers['outliers'] / _outliers['outliers'].sum()) * 100
# Shows max value in the column
_outliers["max_val"] = df[_outliers.index].max()
# Shows min value in the column
_outliers["min_val"] = df[_outliers.index].min()
# Shows median value in the column
_outliers["median"] = df[_outliers.index].median()
# Shows mean value in the column
_outliers["mean"] = df[_outliers.index].mean()
```

That yields:

```
|    |   outliers |   percent |   max_val |   min_val |   median |     mean |
|:---|-----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|---------:|
| A  |          2 |   22.2222 |       665 |         0 |        5 |  61.6923 |
| B  |          3 |   33.3333 |       665 |         0 |        6 | 164.385  |
| C  |          1 |   11.1111 |      1000 |         0 |        4 |  80.9231 |
| D  |          2 |   22.2222 |       665 |         1 |        3 |  77.0769 |
| E  |          1 |   11.1111 |       250 |         0 |        5 |  23.3846 |
```

I would like to calculate the impact of the outliers on the column by calculating the mean and the median without them. I don't want to remove them to do this calculation. I suppose the best way is to add "~" to the outlier filter but I get lost in the code... This will benefit a lot of people as a search on removing outliers yields a lot of results. Other than the why they sneaked in the data in the first place, I just don't think the removal decision should be made without consideration on the potential impact. Feel free to add other considerations (skewness, sigma, n, etc.)

As always, I'm grateful to this community!

EDIT: I added variance and its square root standard deviation with and without outliers. In some fields you might want to keep outliers and go into ML directly. At least, by inspecting your data beforehand, you'll know how much they are contributing to your results. Used with nlargest() in the outliers column you get a quick view of which features contain the most. You could use this as a basis for filtering features by setting up thresholds on variance or mean. Thanks to the contributors, I have a powerful analytics tool now. Hope it can be useful to others.

Comment: Your dataset is clearly not normal and only have very few observation. Using the classical IRQ criterion will censor a lot of data simply because the outlier dominate the mean and provide an interval where there is no data at all. For instance column A will return something like [54; 69] but there is no data at all in this interval. Why not just reject high value based on a percentile criterion, value > P99 are censored?

Comment: this is just an example, maybe it is ill constructed, I'm looking for the code to calculate mean and median if the outliers were to be removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of `apply` method of `DataFrame`.

#### Series genereator

Just define the way you want the robust mean to apply by creating a method consuming `Series` and returning scalar and apply it to your `DataFrame`.

For the IRQ mean, here is a simple snippet:

```
def irq_agg(x, factor=1.5, aggregate=pd.Series.mean):
    q1, q3 = x.quantile(0.25), x.quantile(0.75) 
    return aggregate(x[(q1 - factor*(q3 - q1) < x) & (x < q3 + factor*(q3 - q1))])

data.apply(irq_agg)

# A     3.363636
# B    14.200000
# C     4.333333
# D     3.363636
# E     4.500000
# dtype: float64
```

The same can be done to filter out based on percentiles (both side version):

```
def quantile_agg(x, alpha=0.05, aggregate=pd.Series.mean):
    return aggregate(x[(x.quantile(alpha/2) < x) & (x < x.quantile(1 - alpha/2))])

data.apply(quantile_agg, alpha=0.01)

# A    12.454545
# B    15.777778
# C     4.727273
# D    41.625000
# E     4.909091
# dtype: float64
```

#### Frame generator

Even better, create a function that returns a `Series`, apply will create a `DataFrame`. Then we can compute at once a bunch of different means and medians in order to compare them. We can also reuse Series generator method defined above:

```
def analyze(x, alpha=0.05, factor=1.5):
    return pd.Series({
        "p_mean": quantile_agg(x, alpha=alpha),
        "p_median": quantile_agg(x, alpha=alpha, aggregate=pd.Series.median),
        "irq_mean": irq_agg(x, factor=factor),
        "irq_median": irq_agg(x, factor=factor, aggregate=pd.Series.median),
        "standard": x[((x - x.mean())/x.std()).abs() < 1].mean(),
        "mean": x.mean(),
        "median": x.median(),
    })

data.apply(analyze).T

#       p_mean  p_median   irq_mean  irq_median   standard        mean  median
# A  12.454545       5.0   3.363636         3.0  11.416667   61.692308     5.0
# B  15.777778       6.0  14.200000         5.0  14.200000  164.384615     6.0
# C   4.727273       4.0   4.333333         4.0   4.333333   80.923077     4.0
# D  41.625000       4.5   3.363636         3.0   3.363636   77.076923     3.0
# E   4.909091       5.0   4.500000         5.0   4.500000   23.384615     5.0
```

Now you can filter out outlier in several ways computes relevant aggregate on it such as mean or median.

Comment: what I don't understand is how you can capture both ends of the spectrum of values with the "cutoff". It seems to be computing values whilst trimming only the upper part of the column values. For example, column B has 3 outliers, if you remove them, you get a mean of 14,2 and a median of 5. Your cutoff of .95 considers the quantile to be in between 0<q>95% of values... I need IQR to be the reference to determine outliers, not a range of column values from 0. We need to catch upperbound and lowerbound outliers. Unless I'm not getting your approach.

Answer (score 1):

No comment on whether this is an appropriate method to filter out your outliers. The code below should do what you asked:

```py
q1, q3 = df.quantile([0.25, 0.75]).to_numpy()
delta = (q3 - q1) * 1.5
min_val, max_val = q1 - delta, q3 + delta
outliers = (df < min_val) | (max_val < df)

result = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "outliers": outliers.sum(),
                "percent": outliers.sum() / outliers.sum().sum() * 100,
                "max_val": max_val,
                "min_val": min_val,
            }
        ),
        df.agg(["median", "mean"]).T,
        df.mask(outliers, np.nan).agg(["median", "mean"]).T.add_suffix("_no_outliers"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Result:

```
   outliers    percent  max_val  min_val  median        mean  median_no_outliers  mean_no_outliers
A         2  15.384615     13.5     -6.5     5.0   61.692308                 3.0          3.363636
B         3  23.076923    243.0   -141.0     6.0  164.384615                 5.0         14.200000
C         1   7.692308     13.0     -3.0     4.0   80.923077                 4.0          4.333333
D         2  15.384615     16.0     -8.0     3.0   77.076923                 3.0          3.363636
E         1   7.692308     10.5     -1.5     5.0   23.384615                 5.0          4.500000
```

Comment: all here...df.mask(outliers, np.nan).agg(["median", "mean"]).T.add_suffix("_no_outliers")
], axis=1) and missing from my skills! Thanks

Comment: Thanks (just realized there's a little error in outliers.sum().rename("percent") / len(df) * 100, as it uses the number of outliers not their values to calculate what percentage of the data in the column they weigh.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Fixed

Comment: What you did is fine but I think I might have expressed what I wanted unclearly. I want to see how much outliers' values "weigh" with respect of all other values in the column. Since my example is exaggerated, the numbers will off the roof but I'm looking for the code to do that. Here we simply count them so percent is not right. We can keep percent but introduce weight in terms of values?

Comment: and this outliers.sum().sum() in your code should be len(df) no?